# Random posts in WP_Query when searching by tag

Tags: wp-query, query, tags

I have a section that want to include featured posts. I want to look for featured posts based on tag. For example, I want to fetch all the latest posts that have the featured tag.

I use the following query to do that

```
$featPosts = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'tag_slug__in' => 'featured', //The tag-slug
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order_by' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
));
wp_reset_query();
```

The issue here is that some random posts appear that don't have the featured tag.

Any idea why this might be happening? Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tag_slug__in` should be an array, not a string, that is why your query fails

```
'tag_slug__in' => ['featured'], // Requires PHP 5.4+, use array( 'featured' ) pre 5.4
```